# How to import my python file in another file in visual studio code

Tags: python, selenium, import, module, traceback

I am using python/selenium in visual studio code. I am trying to import my another python class driverScript which resides in executionEngine module and in the file DriverScript. I have imported as below:

```
import driverScript from executionEngine.DriverScript
```

It is producing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Selenium/Selenium-Python Framework/RK_Practice/Tests/mainTest.py", line 5, in <module>
  from executionEngine.DriverScript import driverScript
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'executionEngine'
```

How can I import correctly? Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the script you are wishing to import is not in the current directory, you may want to take this approach:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/script/folder')

import driverScript from executionEngine.DriverScript
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where `executionEngine` is supposed to come from. If it's from a package installable via a package manager such as pip or Anaconda, looks like it's not properly installed. If you installed it yourself, you probably need to add the directory containing `executionEngine` to your PYTHONPATH, so the Python interpreter can find it. This can be done in the VSCode environment files. See the PYTHONPATH section in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: executeEngine is a folder in which the file DriverScript.py existed. And I am trying to import this from another file mainTest.py which resides in Tests folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your python file is on the same level in dir, then you can import just by calling:

```
import filename
```

If your python file is inside another folder, then you need to create a blank `__init__.py` file that will help python to understand it's a package. Then you can import that as follows:

```
from folderName import filename
```

Comment: Python file is inside another folder. Where should I create blank ini.py file? Is it in the folder where called python file existed (or) in the folder from where I am calling?

Comment: folder where called python file existed

Comment: create ini.py  twoo underscore before and after the ini

Comment: Created as suggested. No use. Still issue existed :(

Comment: I have attempted to select python init generator as mentioned in link below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SeeLog.python-init-generator

Steps are given as below:

1. Open your workspace or directory.
2. Press Ctrl(Cmd) + Shift + P
3. Just select Python init Generator: Generate __init__.py

But, Python Init Generator is not available on search in Command Palette. 

Do I need to configure or install something to see this in Command Palette.